# Deploying to firebase without --token, using Service account on a pipeline

Tags: firebase, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to switch from the `firebase deploy whatever --token ...` to use the new service account

I generated the service account json, but i don't know which command am I supposed to run now instead of the one with --token

Any ideas? Thanks